# Какую литературу почитать по C#?

Tags: c#, книги

Всем привет. Сейчас начиная писать на C#.

Посоветуйте литературу по C#, какая книга лучше? Есть опыт программирования в С,Делфи, паскаль).

Заранее спасибо большое!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Шилдт Г.- C# 4.0 полное руководство.

Answer (score 2):

Ещё автор Карли Ватсон у него тоже хорошие книги.

Answer (score 2):

Эндрю Троелсен Язык программирования C# 2010 и платформа .NET 4

Бен Ватсон   С# 4.0 на примерах